# depth and RGB registration error in Kinect pointcloud data

Tags: kinect, pcl, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set the parameter 'depth_registration' = TRUE, available in the openni.launch file in the package openni_launch. Still the point cloud stream shows a mismatch in depth and RGB data.
I observed the point cloud data using rviz.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS fuerte.

I wish somebody could give me some tips about how to correct this mismatch error. One way is to change the transformation manually by hit and trial. But it would be really helpful, if some kind of automatic procedure is available in ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202939/depth-and-rgb-registration-error-in-kinect-pointcloud-data/) by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2015-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-02-11**:
Please can you show us the error and what the stream shows you !

**Comment by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) on 2015-03-11**:
[Check this link](https://imgur.com/mkrY57L). The colors are shifted towards left even in depth_registered point clouds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

probably because of calibration

---

Originally posted by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) with karma: 150 on 2015-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0